# Is Entity Bean not supported in J2EE specification?

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, ejb

I am reading J2EE6 tutorial Jakarta EE as it is called now. In that it says that there are 2 types of enterprise beans one is session bean and second is message driven bean. There is no mention of Entity Bean (BMP & CMP). I guess now Entity Bean is not part of EJB components, while for entity bean Java class annotated with JPA @Entity should be used?

Comment: FYI: The name "J2EE" was already replaced by "Java EE" in 2006 and later replaced by "Jakarta EE" in 2019. Update your learning resources.

Answer (score 2):

Don't panic!

JPA is still here: https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jakartaee-tutorial/#persistence

P. S. TOC of Jakarta EE 9 tutorial: https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jakartaee-tutorial/